# Binary Feature Extraction

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction

I am a beginner in feature extraction for natural language processing purposes.
I want to know how I can use a hashmap to extract features for a text. If each feature is a "key" in hashmap and its value is the "value" (all the features are binary, 0 or 1), does it mean that I need to have n hashmap (n is the number of words in the text)? Because for each word I need to extract the features.

Am I right?

Thanks in advance,
Alice

Comment: The problem described here seems to have been caused by a format error in the input (see the final comment on the answer). Voting to close as "too localized".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can implement this with a hash map however depending on the number of features and your memory requirements it may not be the best or fastest data-structure, it really depends on your domain. Generally, representing features as present or not will yield poor results. A better method is to use TF-IDF when weighting your features.

The approach you are talking about is the "bag-of-words" approach. This is where you tokenize the document base on word boundaries and use the words as features. As a first pass you should remove stop words (ie "a", "and", "the") and then normalize your data (ie Now == now == nOw). You can then perform word stemming to further reduce your vector size.

A good way to understate now to extract features is to take a look at [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/fst.php). 
I have a very simple implementation of Naive Bayes with a parser for RCV-1 that you can look at for an example [Naive Bayes](https://github.com/shanep/NaiveBayes/blob/master/NaiveBayes/src/main/java/edu/boisestate/classify/NaiveBayes.java)

Comment: Thank you Shane, MALLET is exactly what I am using! And I was preparing the input data for that. What I have right now is in this format: Word Label F1:v1 F2:v2 F3:v3. I use SVMlight format. Is that correct? The result I obtained for my classifier was awful but apparently it looked that there is nothing wrong with the input data. Am I correct? Have I prepared the input data correctly?

Comment: How was your corpus labeled? Yes your format looks correct. Do you have a balanced dataset? Also if this helped you out don't forget to up-vote :)

Comment: Also do you have access to the raw text that is not in SVMlight format? Another approach is to Build a pipeline in MALLET using the built in features. Take a look at http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/import-devel.php. Are you embedding MALLET into an existing application or are you just running it from the command line?

Comment: Thanks for complete response. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to vote it up! I tried that :( that's really a pity!

Comment: I have labeled a small corpus myself, so it includes the labels that I want. I have the raw data, labeled data and everything. I use it from command line. When I tried to use it in my application, by adding pipeline, the program faces some errors like this

Comment: : Value (labelProb=69.20583023466637 prior=0.0) loglikelihood = -69.20583023466637
Value (labelProb=110.62119961575098 prior=0.4999999999999999) loglikelihood = -111.12119961575098
Value (labelProb=57.61856946896551 prior=0.05762784468890764) loglikelihood = -57.67619731365442
Value (labelProb=55.87638519199757 prior=0.0425350686013502) loglikelihood = -55.918920260598924
Value (labelProb=55.474437239841464 prior=0.04672344028071541) loglikelihood = -55.52116068012218
 I don't know what the problem is, but what I see is that it has understood my meaning wrongly!!!

Comment: Each V shows the value of one feature. and the pipes that I use are these:pipeList.add(new Input2CharSequence("UTF-8"));

Comment: Pattern tokenPattern =
                Pattern.compile("[\\p{L}\\p{N}_]+");

        pipeList.add(new CharSequence2TokenSequence(tokenPattern));
        pipeList.add(new TokenSequenceLowercase());

Comment: pipeList.add(new Target2Label());
        // Now convert the sequence of features to a sparse vector,
        //  mapping feature IDs to counts.
        pipeList.add(new FeatureSequence2FeatureVector());

        // Print out the features and the label
        pipeList.add(new PrintInputAndTarget());

Comment: the result that I get is something like this:name: WordName
target: LABEL1
input: 0(0)=5.0
1(1)=1.0

Comment: 0(0)=5.0 means that it has counted the number of 0s in the line! but I don't want to add up them! they show different things! and if I remove the pipe which is related to this task, there are some errors. I read all the guidelines of MALLET but I couldn't find anything helpful for my task!

Comment: sorry for long questions! And at the meantime, as soon as I have enough reputation, surely I will vote your answer up. That was really a to the point answer! Without any complexity. Tnx

Comment: How small is your corpus? How many examples do you have? Also what algorithms are you using in MALLET?

Comment: I use MaxEnt and the corpus includes just 9000 words.

Comment: So you have 9000 words, but how is that organized? Is that one big document or is it 9000 words distributed evenly among a whole bunch of documents. What is the distribution of your labels? For example if you have label X and label Y how many documents do you have that have a label of X and how many do you have of label Y. My guess is you don't have enough data do train with or your dataset is highly unbalanced which is affecting your results.

Comment: I have just one document and I don't want to do document classification. I want to label the words of one document. In other words, I have a labeled document to use as a training set. I want to train a classifier and use it on another unlabeled test data.

Comment: I could find the problem of my result. It was malformatting of the data. It must be "Label f1:v1 f2:v2 ..." but what I had was "word label f1:v1 f2:v2"

Comment: However, now I have another problem which I explain here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472998/mallet-classification-for-svmlight-format           . Thank you a lot, you helped me very much