# Text Feature Representation As Vectors for SVM

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining, feature-selection, semantic-analysis

I am learning the Semantic Role Labeling (SRL) task. I have read a lot, and now I come to a problem for how to represent the text features as vectors.

For example, for the sentence:

`We like StackOverflow very much`

given the predicate verb: `like`, a few features are:

```
the left 1st word: I
the right 1st word: StackOverflow
the POS tag of the left 1st word: Pronoun
The POS tag of the right 1st word: Adverbial
```

**What are the right ways to represent these features as vectors?**

If possible, can you also give me some guidances for how to normalize these features please?

I basically want to train the data with these type of features using `SVM` models.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what classifier you use (SVM or not) the feature generation for text is the same. 
I suggest you to take a look at this: 
[Binary Feature Extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257553/binary-feature-extraction)

Also this library would make your life much easier: 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/LBJ
A tutorial is here: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/tutorial.201310